# Paypal express - double order status feedback through IPN

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, payment

since a couple of weeks we are using a fulfillment company to ship our orders. This company will import all orders with the status processing (payment OK).

For orders paid with **paypal** we have some issues because paypal will give a order status feedback 2 times with sometimes more then 30 minutes in between. This will mean the order status is already changed to the order status of the fullfilment company but will be changed back to processing by paypal.

You can see the feedback 2 times in the screenshot.

[image: paypal ipn]

**I tried to change the status with below instruction but that doesn't work.**

[Set new order paid via PayPal Express to 'Pending'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62052/set-new-order-paid-via-paypal-express-to-pending)