# Set new order (especially PayPal Express Checkout) to 'pending'

Tags: paypal, order-status, paypal-express

I am using **Magento 2.2**. Usually all my orders are set to "**Pending**" *except for* "**PayPal Express Checkout**":
These orders are set to "**Processing**". Now I want to have new Paypal Express Checkout orders to be "Pending" aswell.

I already checked this post:
[Set new order paid via PayPal Express to 'Pending'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62052/set-new-order-paid-via-paypal-express-to-pending)
but it did not work for me, maybe because it is Magento 1.

Does someone have a solution?